# Using "socket" (not "io") in Express routes

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

My understanding of the difference between `io.emit()` and `socket.emit()` is that io sends to all connected clients, whereas `socket.emit()` sends only to the connected client.

I've seen the pattern with express where you can bind the `io` instance to the response, and then use it in your route handlers...

```
const io = require('./socket/index')(server);

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.io = io;
    next();
});
```

How can I attach the "socket" to the request/response object in order to emit events *only* to the connected client?

For example:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {

    io.on('connection', (socket) => {
        res.socket = socket;
    });

    next();
});

app.post('/upload', (req, res) => {
    // emits only to the client in question
    res.socket.emit('upload started');
})
```

Comment: You have to create some association between the socket for a user and a request from that same user.  Usually, this is done with a cookie or a session object so you can tell which socket is associated with which express session.  There are some packages which will do this for you.  You need a way to associate every incoming http request to some userID or sessionID.  Then, when they connect their socket.io connection, you can use that same userID or sessionID from the incoming socket.io connect and can store the resulting socket in a way that when an http request comes in, you can associate.

Comment: I'm not using express sessions, but rather JWT tokens. Could I dump a socket ID into an server-render HTML? If I do, how do I then use the socket ID to perform `socket.emit()`?

Comment: Is the JWT token presented when the socket.io connection is made?  I don't see any of your JWT token code so I can't really say much about how you're doing things with that.

Comment: Fair enough, is associating sockets with sessions/JWT tokens the only way to accomplish this? I'd rather not couple the two.

Comment: Well, you have to couple the `socket` to something that identifies the user when they make an HTTP request.  You can make a new cookie when the user authenticates if you want and use that cookie to associate the `socket` to the user.  But, you have to have something that it presented to the server both on a regular HTTP request and when the socket.io connection is initiated (which is also an HTTP request).  If you only have JWT tokens today to identify users and you don't want to use those with socket.io, then you will have to create something else you can use.  That's  just how http works.

Comment: Surely, you can see how a socket.io connection has to identify itself somehow to the server so you can know which user it is, right?  And, then you need to be able to use that same identifying information when an incoming HTTP request comes into your Express server so you can then associate which `socket` belongs to the user making this HTTP request, right?

Comment: I do see that, yes. What about the solution I expressed prior? If I'm rendering the HTML template page for an app, couldn't I dump the socket.id in the HTML, thus giving the client access to the id that she can send with each request.

Comment: Yes, you could do that.  It has little security associated with it if that matters since the client can send any id it wants.  Not sure why you wouldn't just coin an encrypted cookie on the server and then let that be automatically sent (that is essentially what a session cookie is).  That's the point of cookies (to associate a particular browser/user with repeated HTTP requests).

Comment: Hmm, do you have an example of such an implementation? I haven't worked much with cookies.

Comment: express-session does all this for you.  If you just want to read about cookies, Express has features for setting or getting a cookie.  You can read about it in their doc.

Comment: `express-session` looks great, but I don't want to incorporate sessions or Redis into my application, I just want to the server and client to be mutually aware of the socket.id. I'll take a look at using Express cookies.

Comment: You don't need redis with express-session unless you're using clustering (multiple express processes all trying to access the session data).  Really express-session is just an encryption layer around a cookie and then a database storage plug-in architecture if you want your sessions to be persistent across server restarts (which you probably don't).  So, you could be in business with express-session with only a few lines of code when using this https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-socket.io-session.  So, I'm really not sure why you're reinventing stuff people have already built for you.

Comment: I'm certainly not trying to reinvent things that have been built. I just don't want to unnecessarily throw technologies (like session management, redis) that introduce complexity and don't target the root of my problem. Maybe session management _is_ what I'm looking for. I do have two instances running the same express app that are being load balanced, but I don't need to persist any data across them. Do you think `express-socket.io-session` satisfies my use case?

Comment: @jfriend00 does this package (npmjs.com/package/express-socket.io-session) work without using express-session?

Comment: A simple look at the doc page I linked you to earlier for express-socket.io-session shows you that it uses express-session (it's built on top of that).  The point is that you need a session.  Get one that's already written or make your own from scratch.  Your choice.  If you aren't using sticky load balancing (where a given user always goes to the same server instance), then you will need redis to have shared session state no matter which instance the user hits, their server-side session info and socket.io socket will be accessible.  There is sample code in the doc.  Please read that.

Comment: It's unfortunate that I have to introduce so many libraries to accomplish the simple task of getting a socket.id from a express route request. The alternative would not be writing my own, it would just be opting out for complexities' sake. Thanks for your patience through all of these questions, I really appreciate it.

Comment: What's complex is writing it yourself.  It's not complex to grab a pre-built library and specify a few lines of configuration and initialization code and you're up and running with well tested and maintained code.  That is the single biggest advantage of programming in node.js (the entire community of free, open source, pre-built components on NPM).

Comment: Agreed, I'll have to look more into the "secret" with sessions, if it's like an API key, then that means adding that server side to each instance that runs the app, as well as distributing it across a team of developers, which can be a little complex. It may be something that I can just put inline and commit to Github, I'll have to look more into it.

Comment: The secret is just used to make sure your cookie is unique and not the same as everyone else's and to detect tampering.  If your Github repository is private, then yes you can just check it in and all your developers can have access to the same secret for all your servers.  See [http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/92122/why-is-it-insecure-to-store-the-session-id-in-a-cookie-directly](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/92122/why-is-it-insecure-to-store-the-session-id-in-a-cookie-directly) and read both answers for more info.

Comment: If your repository is public, then you will want to treat the secret the same as you treat other secrets in your project (like database credentials, etc...).  You will probably want to put the secret in a configuration file, make your code read it from there and then distribute the configuration file the same way internally that one might distribute SSL certificates.  For a developer deployment to use while developing the code, any secret can be used.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using express generator in your app.js under the var app = express(); add the following lines

```
 var server = require('http').Server(app);
 var io = require('socket.io')(server);
```

Now at the end of the app.js you will see,  module.exports = app; change it into

```
module.exports = {app: app, server: server};
```

Next, open bin/www in your editor. Change,  var app = require('../app'); into

```
var app = require('../app').app;
```

Then change var server = http.createServer(app); into

```
var server = require('../app').server;
```

Open app.js back up and add this middlewear

```
app.use(function(req, res, next){
 res.io = io;
 next();
});
```

Now you can emit using the code

```
/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.io.emit("emit", "users");
    res.send('respond with a resource.');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep the **socket id**

```
// client
const socket = io.connect($constants.socketUrl,{        
    reconnection:true
});
```

socket.io will return a socket session, which includes an id

```
const clientId = socket.id
```

You need to keep that id somewhere (localStorage, cookies, etc ...).
Then in your server you need to provide that id to send messages to that specific client.
socket.io keep a list of your connected clients just use it.

```
//server, maybe you would need to add --> const socketId = "/#" + socketId
//Here is where you use io you passed previously.
io.sockets.connected[socketId].send(msg);
```

Comment: where is `socket.id` available in the client? You said `socket.io` will "return" a socket session, return it as a result to which call?

Comment: when you establish the connection, `const socket = io.connect` (first part in the example)

Answer (score 0):

I have developed a complete application with socket.io and express generator. Please, go through my blog post and I have also given the link to my repository into my post.

https://medium.com/@mohsinyounas05/configuring-socket-io-with-express-generator-2ce2c778ed68